# How to delete a user and automatically all his relations using 'cascade'?

Tags: mysql, laravel, cascade

I'm trying to delete a user and automatically all his relations using 'cascade'. Not sure how to do it. I'm using mysql.
So far i've made this:

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    //...

    public function profile()

    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
}
```

Profile Model

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Profile migration

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->integer('phone');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

And with tinker I'm tryng to do:

```
$user = App\User::firsts();
$user->delete(); // it deletes only the user

$user->profile->delete(); // it deletes only the profile
```

Comment: I am not aware if it's achivable like this. (I'd be happy to know too) - How I'd achieve it is I'd create a UserObserver and delete required relationships accordingly in there on `delete()` event

Comment: Please check that the tables has InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: Your code should work fine. I Answered my working code bellow. Please have a look. There no need to do relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of Model Events:

```php
class User extends Eloquent
{    
    public static function boot ()
    {

        parent::boot();

        self::deleting(function ($user) {
            // This will be executed right before the user is deleted
            $user->profile->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

This way, whenever you call the `delete()` method on a `User` object, Laravel will fire the `$user->profile->delete();` right before.

Comment: I got it! thanks. For this Model Events the insertion of  " ->onDelete('cascade') " on profile, is mandatory? Still I'm confused of the purpose of 'cascade'..

Comment: No. In fact, your setup should work given that you are using MySQL. This is just a workaround that works even if your onCascase method is not set in the migration file.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a database cascade you could delete the related model when the user is deleted by deleting the related model using the deleting event.

Include this in the Boot function of the User Model:

```
public static function boot ()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::deleting(function (User $user) {

            $user->profile->delete();

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres no need to do relationship staff for working with cascade. This code works fine for me -

Migration:

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->integer('phone');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Controller:
Here `->delete()` can delete both user and profile row

```
public function deleteUser(){
    Auth::user()->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

View Delete Link

```
<a href="{{ route('deleteUser') }}">Delete</a>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/delete', 'HomeController@deleteUser')->name('deleteUser');
```